# How can I display some random posts for users?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and can't think of a way how to do it, for example I have 100 posts in my app, i dont want a user to see all of them, I want him to see only some, just in random way. so not all users see all posts, they see only random ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `inRandomOrder()` combined with `limit()`. In the example below, we take 10 random entries.

```php
$results = Post::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
```

Comment: I can get now posts in random order, but after refreshing page posts get refreshed too, Can I make it fixed?

Comment: Yes, but then you need to store that information in a table. Create a table that holds the user ID and the post IDs, and if the user ID has no entries in there, use the snippet above to insert the rows. Then select posts where they exists in that table for that user.

Comment: I will try to do that, Thank you again

Comment: Can I store it in cache instead of database?

Comment: Sure, you can store the IDs in a cookie or similar - but that will refresh once the cookie expires or the user clears their cookies.

Answer (score 2):

use eloquent `inRandomOrder()` .
check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) for more info

Comment: wont that just put posts in random order? I mean if I have 100 posts will it display only some amount from it or it will display all posts in random order?

Answer (score 1):

this may help you

```
 public function getRandomPost()
{
    $post = Post::inRandomOrder()
        ->where('approved', true)->first();
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', ["id" => $post->id]);
}
```